# Race Condition with ng2-translate

Tags: angular, race-condition, ng2-translate

My `app.component` looks like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

    public constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {

        const userLang = navigator.language.split('-')[0];
        const acceptedUserLang = /(de|en)/gi.test(userLang) ? userLang : 'en';
        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        this.translate.use(acceptedUserLang);
    }
}
```

My `app.routing` has the following definition:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'signUpSuccess/:language', component: SignUpSuccessComponent},
];
```

And my `signUpSuccess.component`:

```
export class SignUpSuccessComponent {

    public constructor(translate: TranslateService, route: ActivatedRoute) {
        translate.use(route.snapshot.params['language']);
    }
}
```

When I load the page with `/signUpSuccess/de`, `app.component` sets the language to `en`, `ng2-translate` starts to fetch the `en.json` from the server, then `signUpSuccess.component` sets the language to `de`, `ng2-translate` starts t fetch the `de.json` from the server. If, for any reason now `de.json` wins the race and arrives first at the client, then the language will switch to `en` when the `en.json` arrives the client. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

See this demo plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/dfhdAI1o6VhVHFcnKmWH?p=preview

You can use this function

```
switchMap()
```

With this function the previous request will be canceled, if they are still pending.

Comment: Thank you for your time, to write the code and help me. But ng2-translate is an angular plugin. I'll look into their code. ... I thought it must be my fault.